# SOAP API Call in PHP

Tags: php, api, soap

I have worked with Tones of REST APIs however my latest project requires that I connect to a SOAP API.

They have provided me with the following example file but I have no idea what I should do in order to make a call to this via PHP.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v7="http://ehsmartlink/CompanySearchReadService/v7" xmlns:req="http://ehsmartlink/CompanySearchReadService/v7/Request">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <v7:searchCompanyByEHId>
     <request>
        <req:eulerId>1042953</req:eulerId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <req:filterClosedCompaniesFlag>false</req:filterClosedCompaniesFlag>
     </request>
     <context>
        <userName>***</userName>
        <userPassword>***</userPassword>
        <languageTextIdentifier>EN</languageTextIdentifier>
        <transactionIdentifier>example 1_1_1: Search a buyer by EHID -> one search result / buyer</transactionIdentifier>
        <policyIdentifier>***</policyIdentifier>
        <policyExtensionIdentifier>***</policyExtensionIdentifier>
        <policyEHBUIdentifier>***</policyEHBUIdentifier>
        <ipAdress>?</ipAdress>
     </context>
  </v7:searchCompanyByEHId>
```

I have been given a username and password and a file called 'EH_SMARTLINK_CompanySearchServiceV7.wsdl'.

I have googled a lot but I have no idea what the first step would be for this.

It is the eulerId - 1042953 that I need to query.

Comment: Cf. http://php.net/soapclient. All you need is to set up the SoapClient using the WSDL and the credentials. Which functions you can call is defined in the wsdl file (and ideally in the docs, if one exists).

Comment: SoapUI is also a useful tool for testing the API calls (before implementing via PHP) - https://www.soapui.org/

Comment: Thanks I’ll have a look I did try to look at the soapclient but I could not match their examples to the example file that they sent me. So I didn’t know what to do. But I will keep searching.

Comment: Since you have the WSDL file. You can generate soap client code from it. You can google the following (generate soap client from WSDL php).